# SUM and Group after Right Join two Tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have two tables and I need to right JOIN then do SUM and Group.

```
    Table1: PRODUCT_NAME

    -------------------------
    Module_Code | Product_ID
    -----------------------------
    0201        | A
    0202        | A
    0205        | A
    0503        | B
    0507        | B
    -------------------------------

    Table2: SF_PASS
    -------------------------------
    Module_Code | Test_Qty | Phase 
    ---------------------------------
    0201        | 10       | 1
    0201        | 20       | 2
    0201        | 50       | 3
    0202        | 20       | 1
    0202        | 20       | 2
    0202        | 20       | 3
    0503        | 3        | 1
    0503        | 4        | 2
    0503        | 5        | 3
```

```
I need the result as:
```

```
    -------------------------
    Product_ID | Test_Qty
    ---------------------------
    A          | 140
    B          | 12
```

Can you help?

Comment: Why do you think you need a right join -- this looks like a left join or an inner join to me.

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Please show your attempt at solving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `INNER JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT
    pn.Product_ID,
    SUM(sp.Test_Qty) AS Test_Qty 
FROM PRODUCT_NAME pn
INNER JOIN SF_PASS sp
    ON sp.Module_Code = pn.Module_Code
GROUP BY
    pn.Product_ID
```

If you want all products to appear even if there are no matching rows in `SF_PASS`, change the `INNER JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    pn.Product_ID,
    COALESCE(SUM(sp.Test_Qty), 0) AS Test_Qty 
FROM #PRODUCT_NAME pn
LEFT JOIN #SF_PASS sp
    ON sp.Module_Code = pn.Module_Code
GROUP BY
    pn.Product_ID;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500894)</kbd>

Comment: I think `SUM(COALESCE(sp.Test_Qty, 0)) AS Test_Qty` is more correct.

Comment: @Hogan I'm not really sure. But with your version, `COALESCE` will be called for every `sp.Test_Qty`, but with mine, it will only be called once. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether to apply `coalesce` before or after `sum`. I would prefer it afterwards (as it was before your edit), i.e. perform a normal `sum` on the column, then, only in case the result is null, make it 0. Feels more natural and should be more efficient.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Agreed. I'll rollback the edit.

Comment: Yes in my version it will "occur" on every row.  There are cases where it will be more correct -- there are some systems that will give you a warning or error.  Consider a select where you are summing two columns.  Some of those columns have null in different rows -- some of the sums invocations will have nulls -- this will give an error or warning.  For DB2 (the one I've seen most recently) it says something like "Null invocation of SUM ignored" or "NULL operands ignored".  In this case it does not matter -- but there are cases where it does.